# I don't understand how to use much and more as a noun here

Tags: pronouns

I don't understand how to use ***much and more*** as ***a noun*** here.

> Kimchi soup is a little more of a challenge.
>
> Doing too much of anything is not good for anyone.

I'm familiar with situations where two of them is used as a modifier, but I don't know how to understand it here. ***Much and more*** is representing a part of challenge and anything? If that is the case, my opinion is that challenge and anything is too abstract that I refer to a part of them. How can I understand them?

Answer (score 1):

> my opinion is that 'challenge' and 'anything' are too abstract [so] that [I should not be able to] refer to a *part* of them

Has my interpolation correctly reflected what you were asking? Assuming it has:

Since *much* and *more* can be used nominally (as pronouns) and as adverbs, you have to discern the function the word is serving in a given phrase.

You can think of nominal *much*  as *a (large) portion of an unidentified or unspecified substance*.  A modifier is required to identify the nature of the substance, and this modifier is often expressed in the form of an *of*-phrase:

**Is there much *of that wine* in your cellar?**

**Drinking too much *of anything* is a bad idea.**

When the *of*-phrase refers to something that is not a substance, nominal *much* is being used **figuratively**:

**Miso soup is not much *of a challenge* for western palates.**

The noun in the of-phrase is being understood metaphorically as something having mass or dimension or size.  But this usage is so second-nature that the metaphorical force is as faint as radiation from the Big Bang. The difficulty of the challenge is being expressed in faintly *concrete* terms.

`Amount of substance <=> degree of difficulty`

For most speakers, this would translate analogically, at a conscious level at least, to a statement of degree: "not very challenging".

Nominal *more* refers to a portion (of unknown size) of an unidentified substance, so that it, too, requires a modifier to identify the substance.

**Do you have more of that wine in your cellar?**
--Yes, I have a little more of it, only a few bottles.
--Yes, I have a good deal more of it, as the wine was on sale, so I bought a case of it.

**Kimchi soup is more of a challenge to western palates.**

The implication (from context) is that kimchi poses a greater challenge than other foods pose.

[P.S.](https://books.google.com/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA399&dq=%22much%20of%20a%20muchness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_pCWVa_dBMHT-QH-g7AY&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22much%20of%20a%20muchness%22&f=false)